# Is there any function can unpack any sequence in Python?

Tags: python

```
a = types.SimpleNamespace()
b = dict()
[a.__setattr__(key, value) for key, value in b]
```

Now I would like to use `map`: `list(map(a.setattr, b.items()))`, but the item of `b.items()` is a tuple, not key and value. I know the Python has [the unpack syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists), so I am curious is there any function can unpack sequence too so that I can use it in `map`.

Comment: Why would you use a simple namespace rather than `a = {k:v for k,v in b.items()}`?

Comment: Should you clarify that you do *not* want to use `lambda` within the map? If not, why is having a tuple an issue?

Comment: [**Don't use comprehensions for side effects!**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects) Use a normal loop instead.

Comment: @cricket_007 because you can access members with `.` syntax rather than string lookups.

Comment: @cricket_007 Ok, lambda is a function too, altough it must be defined by the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.starmap`:

```
In [46]: list(itertools.starmap(a.__setattr__, {'a': '1', 'b': '2'}.items()))
Out[46]: [None, None]

In [47]: a
Out[47]: namespace(a='1', b='2')
```

Though I do not think that list comprenehsion or `list(map` is more readable than a simple loop here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.starmap` to map the sequence of key-value pairs to `a.setattr`:

```
list(starmap(a.__setattr__, b.items()))
```

Comment: Why `map(tuple, b.items())`?

Comment: Indeed. Fixed then. Thanks.